# XSL add attribute value to existing one

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to add a value to an existing attribute using xslt:

XML:

```
<div class="my-page" >
```

Expected result:

```
<div class="my-page content" >
```

I have done it with this **XSL** snippet:

```
<div>
<xsl:attribute name="class">my-page <xsl:value-of
                    select="style"/></xsl:attribute>
```

I think that my approach is not so nice. How can I make this better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure about *nice*, but you are NOT "*adding a value to an existing attibute*"; you are adding an attribute, overwriting the existing one (if there *is* an existing one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for *attribute value templates*.

```
<div class="my-page {style}" />
```

Place any XPath expression in braces, XSLT will evaluate it. However: This works in attribute values only.